# mini-(Docker)-shell

Tags: c, homework, linux, shell, namespaces

I was given an assignment to write a mini-shell:

> To write your own shell, you will need to start with a C program that
>   will prompt the user for input and accept in a number of arguments
>   from a command line. The commands entered will be accepted into your
>   shell and then processed to understand if it is a built in command or
>   something that needs to be executed via `fork`/`exec` (NOTE: No use of
>   `system` function). Your shell should emulate the standard shells in
>   how it deals with background commands ( `&` ). The interaction with your
>   shell should be just like the standard shells. What I mean by this is
>   to have a good usage statement returned if the arguments passed to the
>   shell are not correct, and when there is an error you should send back
>   a useful error, and not exit the shell, just continue.
>
> Namespaces allow for virtualization and sharing of spaces between
>   parent and child processes. This is a part of the Linux operating
>   system since 2008 that allows for the creation of different models to
>   create containers for software applications. The most popular version
>   of Linux namespaces is Docker. Your task for this lab
>   is to create the option inside your shell through “built in” commands
>   to move your shell into a container. The options for different
>   containers can be added together in a `clone` or `clone2` call. Here
>   are some of the options:
>
> - CLONE_NEWIPC   - New namespace for IPC
> - CLONE_NEWUTS   - Setup new hostname and domain
> - CLONE_NEWUSER  - User and group changes
> - CLONE_NEWNET   - New network namespace
> - CLONE_NEWNS    - New mount namespace
>
> When using a `clone` function, you will have the ability to run
>   another function. To test your clone call, you will need to be able
>   to demonstrate the change, and the best way to do that is to spawn
>   another shell to “look around” at what changed. The best way to do
>   this is to spawn another shell using the `system` function call.

Here is my code implementing the above.  Basic testing has been performed and it seems to work as intended:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <linux/sched.h>

#ifndef streq
#define streq(x, y) (strcmp((x), (y)) == 0)
#endif

#define MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH 100
#define MAX_PARAMS 10

typedef struct input
{
    char** params;
    int numParams;
    bool inBackground;
} Command;

// split input into array of parameters
Command* parseCmd(char* input)
{
    // handle bad input
    if (!input || strlen(input) == 0)
        return NULL;

    // allocate space on heap for command struct, and parameter list
    Command *cmd = calloc(1, sizeof(Command));
    cmd->params = calloc(MAX_PARAMS + 1, sizeof(char*));

    // setup strtok_r
    char *next = NULL;
    char *part = strtok_r(input, " ", &next);

    // do-while so we can process first `part`, then rest of `input`
    do
    {
        // check for background, if not found default setting is false
        if (streq(part, "&"))
        {
            cmd->inBackground = true;

            // don't store in parameter list for commands
            continue;
        }

        cmd->params[cmd->numParams] = part;
        ++cmd->numParams;
    }
    while ((part = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &next)));

    return cmd;
}

void freeCmd(Command* cmd)
{
    free(cmd->params);
    cmd->params = NULL;

    free(cmd);
    cmd = NULL;
}

int childFunct(void)
{
    system("sh");
    return 0;
}

int executeClone(Command *cmd)
{

    const int STACK_SIZE = 1024;
    unsigned long flags = 0;

    if (cmd->numParams <= 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "clone command requires arguments\n");
        return 0; // non-fatal error
    }

    if (streq(cmd->params[1], "ipc"))
        flags |= CLONE_NEWIPC;
    if (streq(cmd->params[1], "uts"))
        flags |= CLONE_NEWUTS;
    if (streq(cmd->params[1], "user"))
        flags |= CLONE_NEWUSER;
    if (streq(cmd->params[1], "net"))
        flags |= CLONE_NEWNET;
    if (streq(cmd->params[1], "ns"))
        flags |= CLONE_NEWNS;
    if (!flags)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "clone parameter not recognized\n");
        return 0;  // non-fatal error
    }

    char *stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
    pid_t pid = clone(childFunct, stack + STACK_SIZE, flags, NULL);

    // error
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        char* error = strerror(errno);
        fprintf(stderr, "clone: %s\n", error);
    }

    return 0;
}

int executeCmd(Command *cmd)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    // error
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        char* error = strerror(errno);
        fprintf(stderr, "fork: %s\n", error);
        return 1;
    }

    // child process
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        // will daemonize child if background
        // if (cmd->inBackground)
        //     setpgid(pid, 0);

        // execute command
        execvp(cmd->params[0], cmd->params);

        // error occurred
        char* error = strerror(errno);
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s: %s\n", cmd->params[0], error);
        return 2;
    }

    // parent process
    else
    {
        // wait for child process to finish
        if (!cmd->inBackground)
        {
            int childStatus = 0;
            waitpid(pid, &childStatus, 0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    char input[MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH + 1] = "";
    Command *cmd = NULL;

    while(1)
    {
        // print command prompt
        fputs("> ", stdout);

        // fgets returns NULL on Ctrl+D, so exit the loop on NULL
        if (!fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin))
            break;

        // remove trailing newline character, if any
        if (input[strlen(input) - 1] == '\n')
            input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';

        // split cmd into array of parameters
        cmd = parseCmd(input);

        // handle bad command, continue running
        if (!cmd)
            continue;

        // exit?
        if (streq(cmd->params[0], "exit") || streq(cmd->params[0], "quit"))
            break;

        // test for built-in command
        if (streq(cmd->params[0], "clone"))
        {
            if (executeClone(cmd))
            break;
        }
        else // executable
        {
            if (executeCmd(cmd))
                break;
        }

        freeCmd(cmd);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Avoid a hacker exploit.  The null character is not special when `fgets()` reads it.  So if the first character read is the rare null character, then `input[strlen(input) - 1]` is UB.  `strcspn()` is a nice alternative.

   ```
   if (!fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin)) break;
   //if (input[strlen(input) - 1] == '\n')
   //    input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';
   input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';
   ```
2. Memory leak in `main()`.  Better to `freeCmd(cmd)` after the various `break`s.

   ```
           freeCmd(cmd);
       }
       // add 
       freeCmd(cmd);
   }
   ```
3. Unclear why code is using `long` for flags.  [linux.die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/2/unshare) implies the type should be `int`.  Check your prototype for `clone()` - also its return type.  Is it `int` or `pid_t` [Ref](https://linux.die.net/man/2/clone)?
4. Although code nicely aligns, I'd expect an `if() … else if() …else …` structure rather than `if() … if() …`

   ```
   if (streq(cmd->params[1], "ipc"))
       flags |= CLONE_NEWIPC;
   else /* add */ if (streq(cmd->params[1], "uts"))
       flags |= CLONE_NEWUTS;
   else /* add */ if (streq(cmd->params[1], "user"))
       flags |= CLONE_NEWUSER;
   else {
       fprintf(stderr, "clone parameter not recognized\n");
       return 0;  // non-fatal error
   }
   ```
5. Why try to synchronize the type?  Instead reference the type.  Pedantic, avoid UB of signed overflow, use unsigned math with 1u.

   ```
   //                                      Is this the right type? 
   // cmd->params = calloc(MAX_PARAMS + 1, sizeof(char*));
   //                                    Right size, regardless of type of *cmd->params
   cmd->params = calloc(MAX_PARAMS + 1u, sizeof *(cmd->params));
   ```

Comment: Aren't parameters not "stackable" when you change to the if-else construct?

Comment: @syb0rg Comment is unclear for me -please rephrase - will check later.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood a part of your review.

Answer (score 4):

- **Background task handling**

  You must `wait` for the child process regardless of how it is started, in the background or not. As written, a background command ends up in the zombie state. To let the parent shell to continue, set up a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`, and `wait` there.

  I know the program statement doesn't require it, but it always nice to let user query a return status of last command.
- **`command("sh")`**

  It is unclear from the program statement, which shell should be cloned. In any case, it is highly recommended to supply a full path to `system`.
- **`freeCmd`**

  `cmd->params = NULL` and `cmd = NULL` are meaningless: `cmd = NULL` is invisible to caller, and caller shall not touch `params` of a freed `cmd` anyway.
- **`parseCmd`**

  The code recognizes `&` anywhere within a command line as a background indicator. It doesn't feel right for many reasons: compatibility with existing shells; `&` could be valid character in a filename; etc. I recommend to test for a last argument being `&` after parsing is done, and adjust the command appropriately.
- **Built-in commands**

  Is `clone` the only built-in? If so, your shell is at least unable to `cd`.
- **Misc**

  - You may want to `fflush(stdout)` after printing the prompt.
  - Test what `malloc` returns.
  - It is unclear whether the command line may have quotes and escapes. They are obviously not addressed.

**Edit: handling background termination**

In a nutshell it seems is fairly simple: define a function

```
void handle_child_exit(int signo)
{
    int status;
    wait(&status);
    signal(SIGCHLD, handle_child_exit); // Not always required, but helpful
}
```

and in install it in `main`:

```
    signal(SIGCHLD, handle_child_exit);
```

The reality is a bit hairier, and I can only recommend reading `man signal` and `man sigaction`.

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would set up a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`?

Comment: @syb0rg See edit.

Comment: Why not just install `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN)` in `main` and leave what I have?  Is there an advantage to this method?

Comment: @syb0rg As written, only the foreground command is `wait`ed for. On the other hand, you cannot `wait` on a background command synchronously - it will defeat the purpose of backgrounding - so it is better to do it in a signal handler.

Comment: Disagree with "cmd->params = NULL and cmd = NULL are meaningless: cmd = NULL is invisible to caller, and caller shall not touch params of a freed cmd anyway."  Setting pointers and data that are going to be part of free'd memory, in my experience, more readily exposes mis-use of free'd memory more rapidly than not.  A net debugging benefit vs potential incurred problems.  `cmd = NULL;` after `free(cmd);` is also defensive coding should subsequent code inadvertently use `cmd` as again, more _likely_ to catch coding problems.  Yet agree that it adds no correct code benefit.

Comment: @chux I am probably missing your point. Regardless of what is done to `cmd` in `freeCmd`, it remains the unchanged outside of it. The assignment `cmd = NULL` modifies a local copy, invisible from the context. _If_ the API said `freeCmd(Command ** cmd) { ... *cmd = NULL; }`, that would make a difference.

Comment: @chux `would` is meant to be `could` of course.